# Reject letters and only allow number inputs @ enter first and second number in Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, validation, input

Trying to only allow number inputs in python 3.x no letters and ask user to input a number if they enter a letter. I have two numbers that need to be entered and need it to reject singlarily as they are entered.

```
print ('Hello There, what is your name?') # String asks the user for their name
myname = input() #string
print ('Nice to meet you, '+ myname)# String responds "Nice to meet you" and input the users name that was entered
print() #adds a space
print ('We want to some math today!') # String tells user we want to do some math today
print() # adds a space
num1,num2 = float(input("Enter first number")), float(input("Enter second number"))
sum = num1+num2
if sum  >100 : # Determines if users inputs when added together are  > 100
 print('They add up to a "Big Number" ') # If inputs are > 100 prints "They add up to a big number"
 # and the users name
elif sum <=100 : # Determines if the users inputs when added are = to or <100
 print ('They add up to' ,(sum))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a **while loop** to continuously accept a **valid input** which in your case is a **numerical** one.

Another thing is that you need to **check** if the entered input is numerical or **not**, in that case you can use Python's inbuilt **isdigit()** function to do it.

Lastly, **type cast** your input to **float** or **int** while you add the both to avoid str related errors.

```
print ('Hello there, what is your name?') # String asks the user for their name
myname = input() #string
print ('Nice to meet you, '+ myname) # String responds "Nice to meet you" and input the users name that was entered
print() #adds a space
print ('We want to some math today!') # String tells user we want to do some math today
print() # adds a space

i = False
while i == False:
    num1 = input("Enter first number: ")
    if num1.isdigit():
        i = True
    else:
        i = False

print() # adds a space

j = False
while j == False:
    num2 = input("Enter Second number: ")
    if num2.isdigit():
        j = True
    else:
        j = False

sum = float(num1) + float(num2)
if sum  > 100 : # Determines if users inputs when added together are  > 100
    print('They add up to a "Big Number" ') # If inputs are > 100 prints "They add up to a big number"
 # and the users name

elif sum <= 100 : # Determines if the users inputs when added are = to or <100
    print ('They add up to' ,(sum))
```

Let me know, if that worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

When you are validating multiple inputs, I usually make a separate function to do so. While it may not be necessary here, it is a good habit to factor out repeated code. It will exit if either of the inputs are not floats. Here's how I would do it, using a try block with a ValueError exception. By the way, newlines can be achieved by putting '\n' at the end of the desired strings. Using `print()` is a sloppy way of doing it.

```
import sys
def checkNum(number):
    try:
        number = float(number)
    except ValueError:
        print("That is not a float.")
        sys.exit()
    return number
```

Then, you can use the original code like so:

```
print ('Hello There, what is your name?') #String asks the user for their name
myname = input() #string
print ('Nice to meet you, '+ myname + '\n')#String responds "Nice to meet you" and input the users name that was entered
print ('We want to some math today!\n') #String tells user we want to do some math today
num1 = checkNum(input("Enter first number"))
num2 = checkNum(input("Enter second number"))
sum = num1+num2
if sum  >100 : # Determines if users inputs when added together are  > 100
    print('They add up to a "Big Number" ') #If inputs are > 100 prints "They add up to a big number" and the users name
elif sum <=100 : #Determines if the users inputs when added are = to or <100
    print ('They add up to' ,(sum))
```